# Writing a query that can have excel fill in and consolidate unpopulated fields within a group of duplicates?

Tags: excel, syntax, powerquery, data-cleaning, m

I have a contact info dataset (large) that contains lots of semi-duplicate rows that I'd like to condense into as little rows as possible. Attached is a sample of what I'm talking about.

[image: data sample]

The blue table on the left is smaller scale example of what I'm currently working with. The orange table on the right is what I would like the table to look like.

I want to write a query that will be able to select an ID that has multiple rows, and within that selection, assess whether values can be moved into a parent row that has unpopulated cells (see ID "4" and how I condensed those three rows of data into one by filling in blanks and consolidating duplicates).

An important point of emphasis is how to perform this task without it being a blanket statement for *all* duplicates in the entire worksheet. Ultimately I want to perform this task for the entire worksheet, but I want excel to first isolate a single ID and *then* execute the aforementioned task, rather than evaluating the criteria based on *all* duplicate IDs. ((If that makes sense))

One other condition I would like to have is for certain columns where multiple rows under the same ID have different values, is to allocate that data into a subsequent column (see Tags & Tags2 columns under ID "1") instead of overriding a cell.

- I only want to do this ^ for 2 columns; for the others, have it keep them as separate rows.

This sounds like a task for Power Query, but my knowledge is limited in that realm. Any help on how to construct a query that accomplish this task is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work fine

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Title", type text}, {"Company", type text}, {"Phone", type text}, {"Phone2", type any}, {"Street Address", type any}, {"City", type text}, {"Tags", type text}}),
// group, then unpivot, remove duplicates
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"Data", each Table.Distinct(Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(_, {"ID"}, "Attribute", "Value"), {"Attribute", "Value"}), type table}}),
// combine all the tags into one cell for later splitting
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Group([Data], {"ID", "Attribute"}, {{"Data", each Text.Combine([Value],","), type text}})),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Attribute", "Data"}, {"Attribute", "Data.1"}),
// replace null with Title to preserve rows with no data
#"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Expanded Custom",null,"Title",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Attribute"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Replaced Value",{"Data"}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Columns", List.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Data.1"),
// split the Tags column into any number of columns as needed
#"Replaced Value1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Pivoted Column",null,"xxx",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Tags"}),
DynamicColumnList  = List.Transform({1 ..List.Max(Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value1","Custom", each List.Count(Text.PositionOfAny([Tags],{","},Occurrence.All)))[Custom])+1}, each "Tags." & Text.From(_)),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" =  Table.SplitColumn(   #"Pivoted Column", "Tags",  Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), DynamicColumnList)
in  #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

Comment: Hi horseyride, this looks great. I'll give it a test run in a little bit and let you know if there are any additional issues that arise. I'm aware that the query I'm requesting is quite specific so I appreciate the work.

Comment: Resort rows on index and columns as needed

Answer (score 1):

You can get your desired output from Power Query using just the `Table.Group` function.

I have assumed:

- Output columns are only as you show
- Input columns don't have anything in `Phone2` and `Tags2`

  - If that is not the case, simple modifications are possible
- If there are more distinct entities that columns for the output, they will be output in a single column concatenated.

  - In other words, if you had three tags; the first one would be in the `Tags` column and the second and third concatenated with a comma in the `Tags 2` column.
  - I did it this way because, since you show no examples, I'm not quite sure how you want things lined up if you have, for example, multiple phones and multiple tags.

***Note:** If you want to restrict this to just one ID, just insert a filtering step at the beginning*

**M Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Title", type text}, {"Company", type text}, {"Phone", type text}, {"Phone2", type any}, {"Street Address", type text}, {"City", type text}, {"Tags", type text}, {"Tags2", type any}}),

//Group by ID then
//Depending on how many columns available in results table, will 
//either concatenate, multiple non-duplicate rows, or put them in separate columns
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {
        {"Title", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([Title]),", ")},
        {"Company", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([Company]),", ")},
        {"Phone", each try List.RemoveNulls([Phone]){0} otherwise null},
        {"Phone 2", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveFirstN(List.RemoveNulls(List.Distinct([Phone])),1),", ")},
        {"City", each Text.Combine(List.Distinct([City]),", ")},
        {"Tags", each try List.RemoveNulls([Tags]){0} otherwise null},
        {"Tags 2", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveFirstN(List.RemoveNulls(List.Distinct([Tags])),1),", ")}      
    })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ron, I was experimenting with this earlier and it also does the trick. Thanks for the response!